# c# Generics: Passing List<string> to a method that expects a List<T>

Tags: c#, generics, argument-passing

I've had my first foray into generics, and understand them a little bit.  I have a method intended to accept two lists of any object, match them various ways and return the matched/unmatched objects (the stuff inside the method probably isn't key here).  The purpose is to accept any kind of object, be it customers, or whatever.  However, I've hit a snag with getting it to accept 'string', I'm guessing because it's not initialised with the new() keyword and isn't like a normal instanced class.

So, I have a method declaration like so:

```
public static compareResult<T> stepCompare<T>(List<T> leftList, List<T> rightList, Comparison<T> IDComparer = null, Comparison<T> lowLevelComparer = null, bool confirmUniqueness = true) where T : IComparable, new()
```

Admittedly, adding the where clause at the end was in response to an error "cannot create an instance of the variable type 'T' because it does not have the new() constraint".  This appeared against a line in the method saying

```
T lastItem = new T();
```

However, now if I try to pass it two `Lists<string>`, it says "`'string' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'MF.Comparers.stepCompare<T>(System.Collections.Generic.List<T>, System.Collections.Generic.List<T>, System.Comparison<T>, System.Comparison<T>, bool)'`...

Any way to let this method accept lists whether they be of string or other classes?  Or a shortcut to put lists of string into a type that will be accepted?

Comment: What you want to achieve? In code you write var lastItem = new string(); string doesn't have parameterless constructor. So, rethink your algorithm.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments.  All the comments were right on the money, I marked Marc's as the answer since it was the first one that suggested the default(T) idea.

Comment: Thanks so much everybody! I just learnt about default(T)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want *any object*, you probably have to live without the `new T()`. You *could* do the same with a combination of reflection, special-cases (for `string` etc), and `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()` - however, IMO you should limit yourself (in this case) to `default(T)`, which will be null for reference types (including string) and nullable value-types, and all-zeros for non-nullable value-types. You should also probably use a `bool` or similar to make sure you don't actually *use* that value, except to satisfy definite assignment rules for the compiler.

Comment: Yep that's what it was.  Interestingly I'd had an issue in another spot and changed it to default(T) but left the new() in a few spots.  Thanks for the response mate.

Answer (score 8):

You can't make `string` satisfy the `new()` constraint, no. While `string` *is* a normal class, and instances can be created using constructors in a perfectly normal way, it doesn't have a parameterless constructor.

The best approach really depends on *why* you had that line of code including `lastItem`. If you just want some default value, then `default(T)` is probably the best approach.

If you really *do* want to create a new instance of `T`, then you should probably accept a `Func<T>` in the method's parameter list, as a way of creating a default value on demand. Alternatively, if you're happy using a particular single value as the default, you could just add a parameter of type `T`. It's hard to say without seeing the rest of your code.

Comment: Excellent, thanks Jon!  I have put default(T) and it works like a charm.  Cheers